Are all square-sum keeping linear transformations rotations?
My impression is clearly a yes in the "usual" circumstances (finite dimensional space with real coordinates), except for mirrors.
But I have no idea, where to even start to prove it. On a more formal way, I would ask this:
Can any square-sum keeping transformation be expressed by a combination of finite rotations (around any 2D plane) and mirrors in finite dimensional, real vector space?

What do you mean by "square-sum keeping transformation?"

I think it's that the distance between two points doesn't change (the transformationn is rigid)

@BenSteffan The sum of the square of the coordinates of the transformed vectors is the same after and before the transformation.

Also, in $2$D, you rotate around a $0$D point; in $3$D, you rotate around a $1$D line; in $n$D, you rotate around a $(n-2)$D hyperplane.

@Lucenaposition I am not sure also in that, but I see it very likely, square-sum keeping and linearity has your "rigidity" as a consequence.

@Lucenaposition That is right. But rotation is an inherently 2D thing, it transforms coordinates on a plane, that is true in all dimensions. Your comment about the rotations in 2D, 3D, etc mean only that the plane where we rotate, has obviously a much bigger "degrees of freedom" in more dimensions.

Let $f$ be the transformation. LEt $A,B$ be vectors. Let $0$ be the origin, which is fixed by $f$. Note $f$ being square-sum preserving means $dist(A,0)=dist(f(A),0)$ for all vectors $A$. Then $dist(A,B)=dist(A-B,0)=dist(f(A-B),0)=dist(f(A)-f(B),0)=dist(f(A),f(B))$ so $f$ is distance preserving.

@Lucenaposition Wow! Right. About the original question, somewhere I have read, in 4D space, we can have perpendicular 2D planes whose only intersection is the origin (actually, that is the general case). The combination of two rotations, with different angles, around such a plane pair, is a square sum keeping linear transformation, but it can not be expressed by a single rotation (around any plane). Until 3D, not that is the case, in 3D any square sum-keeping linear transformation can be expressed as a single rotation around an axe (save for mirrors).

The terminology here is missing a little, but I think you are asking about either the Euclidean group $E(n)$ or the Orthogonal group $O(n)$ depending whether you consider translations as "square-sum keeping" which would probably be better written as "distance preserving" or "length preserving".
From your comments I think it is the orthogonal group you are after. You are intending for $0$ to be preserved by all these transformations, yes?
If so then yes all such transformations can be written as the product of "simple rotations" (i.e. a rotation in a given 2D plane and a fixed orthocomplement) or as the product of these plus a reflection in a hyperplane.
To be precise when talking about the Orthogonal group a rotation/reflection fixes the origin (i.e. our plane or hyperplane goes through the origin).
In the Euclidean group case we are expanding the idea of reflections/rotations to include those not around the origin but having done that those will generate the whole group. Two reflections in parallel hyperplanes will give a translation for example.
